# yup validation one character followed by other character using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, yup

I need some yup email validation rules to show some custom messages.

1. invalid if we don't get `@` followed by a `.`

- abc@gmailcom (invalid)
- def.com (invalid)

What I've tried so far:
`yup.string().email().matches(/^(?!\@*.)/)`

2. invalid if we get `@` followed by `,`

- abc@gmail,com (invalid)

What I've tried so far:
`yup.string().email().matches(/^(?!\@*,)/)`

None of the solutions I tried worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
yup.string().email().matches(/@[^.]*\./)
```

and

```js
yup.string().email().matches(/^(?!.*@[^,]*,)/)
```

These two regular expressions match

- `@[^.]*\.`  - a `@` char, then zero or more chars other than `.` and then a `.` char (i.e. there must be a `@` somewhere and then there must be a `.` to the right of the found `@` char)
- `^(?!.*@[^,]*,)` - start of string (`^`), and then a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.*`), then a `@`, then zero or more non-comma chars (`[^,]*`) and then a comma. So, basically, match a string that does not contains a `@` that is followed with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write different patterns to yield different custom messages.

For example, this pattern matches a comma after the @

```
^[^@\s]+@[^@\s,]*,
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^@\s]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or @
- `@` Match literally
- `[^@\s,]*,` Match optional chars other than a whitespace char or @, then match the comma

This pattern matches an email like format. It can also match a comma, but that pattern specific pattern is already being checked for.

```
^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$
```

```js
const getMessage = s => {
  if (s.startsWith("@")) {
    return `${s} -->Invalid, string starts with @`;
  }
  if (/^[^@\s]+$/.test(s)) {
    return `${s} --> Invalid, string does not contain @`;
  }
  if (/^[^@\s]+@[^@\s,]*,/.test(s)) {
    return `${s} --> Invalid, string has , after @`;
  }
  if (/^[^@\s]+@[^@\s.]+$/.test(s)) {
    return `${s} --> Invalid, string has no . after @`;
  }
  if (/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(s)) {
    return `${s} --> Valid format`;
  }
  return `${s} --> Invalid format`;
};
[
  "@test.com",
  "abc@gmailcom",
  "def.com",
  "abc@gmail,com",
  "test@test.com",
  "test@@"
].forEach(s => console.log(getMessage(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just following this and working for me.

https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/507#issuecomment-765799429

```
const emailRegex = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
```

and

```
yup.string().trim().required("Required").email("Invalid email").matches(emailRegex,"Invalid email"),
```